# R.Raw.Test Can't resolve

Tags: android, visualizer

I'm trying to create a visualizer for myself for listening to music on android, and what better way to start than by finding a working example. I found [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/02/create-audio-visualizer-for-mediaplayer.html),
but when I put all the code in the right places, R.raw.test was not found. I can't find anything for it anywhere in the comments section or on google, and when I went to declaration .raw was not listed. It goes from popup something or other to recycle, no raw to be found. If anybody has another example to use I would appreciate that as well as it turns out this example might not work, but obviously this should be a much easier fix than I think it is.

Comment: As the example says: `Copy test.mp3 to /res/raw/ folder`

Comment: try to use com.yourpackagename.R

Comment: Thanks xiaomi, I knew it was something simple, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The resource wasn't found in the correct directory, just moved it over to /raw/